# Sort structs depending on non-static value (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I have an `EnemyRhombus` class. It is a unit, which can move to different points on the map.

I want to process points, to which it can move, in order of increasing distance to them.

To do it I want to sort the points.

Code 1:

```
class EnemyRhombus
{
public:
    int x,y;
    int dist(Point p)
    {
        int dx=abs(p.x-x);
        int dy=abs(p.y-y);
        return dx+dy-min(dx,dy);
    }
    bool points_cmp(Point f, Point s)
    {
        return dist(f)<dist(s);
    }
    void move()
    {
        vector<Point> candidates;
        //...
        sort(candidates.begin(),candidates.end(),points_cmp);
    }
}
```

does not compile. Prints

[Error] no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, < unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Code 2:

```
class EnemyRhombus
{
public:
    int x,y;
    static int dist(Point p, int tx, int ty)
    {
        int dx=abs(p.x-tx);
        int dy=abs(p.y-ty);
        return dx+dy-min(dx,dy);
    }
    template<int X, int Y> static bool points_cmp(Point f, Point s) 
    {
        return dist(f,X,Y)<dist(s,X,Y);
    }
    void move()
    {
        vector<Point> candidates;
        //...
        sort(candidates.begin(),candidates.end(),points_cmp<x,y>);
    }
}
```

produces errors:

[Error] 'EnemyRhombus::x' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'EnemyRhombus::y' cannot appear in a constant-expression

---

How can I solve the problem?

---

Usage of examples from answers may produce errors and warning, saying that c++ 11 is enabled by default, which is not true (At least, in orwell dev-cpp).
To make them work, one should add `-std=c++11` to compiler commands.
(Tools->Compiler Options -> Genera  in my case)

Comment: `points_cmp` is a non-static member function and thus needs to be given an object to work on.

Comment: But how can I pass it to `sort` and give `this` as object?

Comment: `sort(candidates.begin(),candidates.end(), [this](Point a, Point b) { return this->points_cmp(a, b); });`

Comment: Since `points_cmp` doesn't use any of the current object's instance-specific data, make it static or make it a free function.

Comment: In `dist` body: `int dx=abs(p.x-x);`

Comment: It uses `dist`, which is non-static, I think you meant. A bind, lambda, or functor would all work in this case, one of which Igor posted above, and another POW posted below.

Comment: In case you're working with stone-age tools, a functor is also possible. [Shown **here**](http://pastebin.com/ER82y1s3), as none of the answers below mentioned it. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a C++11 lambda as well apart from using static/out-of-class functions or use the method suggested by P0W.

```
std::sort(candidates.begin(),candidates.end(),
    [&](Point f, Point s) { return dist(f) < dist(s); }
);
```

The lambda takes care of the order in which to sort.

Comment: [Error] no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<Point>::iterator, std::vector<Point>::iterator, EnemyRhombus::move()::<lambda(Point, Point)>)'

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort` can't use `points_cmp` because it doesn't have `this` pointer, as you are trying to pass a pointer to a member function, so

If your compiler support C++11, you can use :

```
std::sort( candidates.begin(),
           candidates.end(),
           bind(&EnemyRhombus::points_cmp, this, _1, _2));
```

Or else make function `static` or a free function out of class

Answer (score 2):

In case of Code1 c++14 alows to do even better:

```
std::sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end(), [this] (auto a, auto b) {
  return points_cmp(a, b);
});
```

Comment: @POW AFAIK, no... It compiles fine with clang 3.5. See examples in section 5.1.2 of the latest standard.

Comment: Hmm I see..well it doesn't with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d83a5e207c94f5c)

Comment: @POW I think it will be able to compile it if you replace `auto` with `Point` type, than this lambda will be c++11 compatible. c++14 support is not complete gcc4.9 (I assume you tried this version?). I hope to try it with gcc5 in a few month :)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a *lambda* to sort the `vector<Point>` in a custom way; the customized sorting order can be specified in the body of the lambda (note that lambdas are available starting from C++11):

```
void move()
{
    std::vector<Point> candidates;
    //...

    //
    // Specify your custom sorting using a lambda:
    // 
    std::sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end(), [this](Point f, Point s) {
        return dist(f) < dist(s);
    });
}
```

Note also that in the lambda you must use the **`[this]`** *capture* syntax, since you are calling the `dist()` non-static member function inside the body of the lambda.

---

In addition, if your `Point` class is *not* cheap to copy, consider passing it using `const&` (to avoid useless *"deep copies"*):

```
std::sort(candidates.begin(), 
          candidates.end(), 
          [this](const Point& f, const Point& s) {
              return dist(f) < dist(s);
          }
);
```